# Hide/Show by hiding one element first, then showing the item clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, coldfusion

I have three radio buttons on a form.  When a radio item is selected, a sub menu will appear just below the radio option.  I'd like to have it when the radio button is clicked, the other sub menu will hide first, then the sub menu corresponding to the now selected radio button will appear.

Question:  How would I slideUp the currently shown submenu before displaying the clicked radio option (slideDown).

NOTE:  I'm using Coldfusion.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<form > 
<!--- Work Efforts --->
<input name="ArchRpt" type="radio" value="WorkEfforts" id="ArchRpt_WorkEfforts" onclick="SetArchRpts('ArchRpt_WorkEfforts');"/>
Work Efforts (WE)<br />
<div id="ArchRpt_WorkEfforts_sub" class="Indent25" style="display:none;">
    some additional form options here
</div>
<!--- Previous Week Status Updates --->
<input style="clear:both;" name="ArchRpt" type="radio" value="StautsUpd" id="ArchRpt_StautsUpd" onclick="SetArchRpts('ArchRpt_StautsUpd');" />
Previous Week Status Updates<br />
<div id="ArchRpt_StautsUpd_sub" style="display:none;">
    some additional form options here
</div>
<!--- Monthly Accomplishments REPORT --->
<input name="ArchRpt" type="radio" value="MoAccompl" id="ArchRpt_MoAccompl" onclick="SetArchRpts('ArchRpt_MoAccompl')" />
Monthly Accomplishments (MA)<br />
<div id="ArchRpt_MoAccompl_sub" style="display:none;">
    some additional form options here
</div>
</form>
```

and the js:

```
<script Language="JavaScript">
function SetArchRpts(RadioOption){
$('#'+RadioOption).attr('checked', true);

if (RadioOption == 'ArchRpt_WorkEfforts'){
    $('#ArchRpt_WorkEfforts_sub').slideDown();
    $('#ArchRpt_StautsUpd_sub').slideUp();
    $('#ArchRpt_MoAccompl_sub').slideUp();
}
else if (RadioOption == 'ArchRpt_StautsUpd'){
    $('#ArchRpt_WorkEfforts_sub').slideUp();
    $('#ArchRpt_StautsUpd_sub').slideDown();
    $('#ArchRpt_MoAccompl_sub').slideUp();
}
else if (RadioOption == 'ArchRpt_MoAccompl'){
    $('#ArchRpt_WorkEfforts_sub').slideUp();
    $('#ArchRpt_StautsUpd_sub').slideUp();
    $('#ArchRpt_MoAccompl_sub').slideDown();
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Give a common class name to all your divs in above code. Say you gave them a class name 'sub-divs'. Now in SetArchRpts function add a line of code $('.sub-divs').slideUp(). I think thats what you want.

Comment: The actual question has been restated in the details above and not just in the title.

Comment: @mysterious I see where you are going with this.  Nice.

Comment: let me know if it works. I will make my comment an answer and then you can accept it.

Comment: @mysterious it didn't work but is on the right track.  It's almost like the order in which the effects are firing need to be ordered or something.  I'll see if I can create a jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank you to the you guys for helping me out.  Great answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too much of repetitive code and Selector wrong in the first place ..

```
$('##'+RadioOption)
```

Supposed to be

```
$('#'+RadioOption); // Need to use only a single pound #
```

You can write up the whole code in a single function..

```
$('input[name="ArchRpt"]').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('div[id*="ArchRpt"]').slideUp();
        $(this).nextAll('div').first().slideDown();
    }
});​
```

[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/mAy4s/1/)

**EDIT**

This is just **a hack** .. You can try this way..

```
var checkedId = '';
$('input[name="ArchRpt"]').on('click', function() {
    if (this.id !== checkedId) {
        checkedId = this.id;
        $('div[id*="ArchRpt"]').slideUp();
        $(this).nextAll('div').first().slideDown();
    }
});​
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/mAy4s/2/)

Comment: Looks like he/she is using ColdFusion so if that # is in an CFOUTPUT context, ## will convert to a single pound.

Comment: The code is CF and the double # ("##") is used as an escape character.  I'll update the code to be used as HTML.  Thanks for catching this.

Comment: I didn't know about that .. Check fiddle

Comment: @Sushanth-- From the fiddle, I can visually see yours is working as I wanted.  Let me try it in my code.

Comment: We have a winner.  This works great.  One question though... In IE8, there is a flicker when the effects complete.  Is there a way to prevent that?  IE is our company standard so I have to try to make it work.

Comment: I didn't see this before but if you click on a selected radio option, the behavour will repeat again.  Can the function be tweaked so that if the item is already checked to not perform the effect?

Comment: the fiddle isn't flickering but it is in my code - either because I have more "stuff" in the sub area than what is in the fiddle, I'm not sure.  I searched SO and apparently this is a known issue.  I'll read through those solutions to see if any of them will fix this.  In the meantime, I'll mark your answer correct.

Comment: @dlackey .. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fhZnF/1/)

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("click", function() {
    if ( $( "#" + this.id + "_sub" ).is(":visible") ) return;

    $("div[id^=ArchRpt_]").slideUp();
    $( "#" + this.id + "_sub" ).slideDown();
});
```

Just a note - if you're using jQuery you should utilize its event listeners and not use `onclick`-s.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just being lazy.  I'm updating an OLD form.

Comment: deleting code is much easier then adding new :) you can safely remove all the `onlick`-s and make your markup cleaner.. shortening up your JS is a very good idea as well ;-)

Comment: If you click the same radio twice, the behavior is repeated.  But the fiddle does appear to do what I need.  Let me port it over into my code and I'll let you know.

Comment: This one also works.  Yours flickers, too in IE8.  Can this be fixed or is this just a browser issue I need to live with?

Comment: No IE8?  You are soooo lucky! LOL  Interesting fix I must say.

Comment: It should be noted that this worked, too.  I did give it a +1 since the code is so clean.

Answer (score 1):

Here: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5tr2Q/6/)

```
$('input[name="ArchRpt"]').on('click', function(){
    var $sub = $('#'+$(this).attr('id')+'_sub');
    $('#ArchRpt_WorkEfforts_sub, #ArchRpt_StautsUpd_sub, #ArchRpt_MoAccompl_sub').not($sub).slideUp();
    $sub.slideDown();
});
```

Comment: On your jsFiddle, if you select a radio option and then click it again, the effect is repeated.  Do you know how to correct that so it wont trigger the event a second time?  To reproduce, select the first radio option.  Then, click it again and you'll see the behavior.

Comment: @diackey - Sorry about that! Updated.

Comment: Your update resolved the repeated action.  Looks like all three solutions so far flicker in IE8 when the effect is completed.

Comment: I can't test in IE. But that's not a problem you should consider. The jQuery team make the best choices so that it moves smoothly. You can't use css3 animate either, because IE 8 doesn't support it. It is not a better solution to do it I guess. :)

Comment: +1 for a working solution.  Your line which reads, `$('#ArchRpt_WorkEfforts_sub, #ArchRpt_StautsUpd_sub, #ArchRpt_MoAccompl_sub').not($sub).slideUp();` could be shortened like the other samples [e.g. `$("div[id^=ArchRpt_]").slideUp();`   ].